# Can't run zsh script that's in path

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I've been trying to run a simple script named 'post-install.sh':

```
#!/bin/zsh
sudo apt-get update -y
```

This script is in ~/bin.

Relevant commands:

```
% echo $PATH
/home/$USER/bin:/usr/local/bin:/home/$USER/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

My ~/.zshrc has:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

My ~ directory has (among others):

```
.bashrc
.profile
.xinitrc
.zshrc
```

My /etc directory also has a zsh file but I haven't modified it.
My ~/.bashrc doesn't seem to have anything relevant (I've tried adding 'source ~/.bashrc' to my .zshrc).

I'm running Debian 10 on a Thinkpad x230.

EDIT: I've tried running my script from '/usr/local/bin' as well. I've also tried running my script as:

```
sudo post-install.sh
sudo zsh post-install.sh
post-install.sh
```

My script *does* run when I run the absolute path:

```
sudo ~/bin/post-install.sh
```

Comment: Assuming the script is executable, did you just recently (in the same shell session) move the script to its current location? If so, does `rehash` (in the interactive `zsh` session) make it available as `post-install.sh`?

Comment: I 'chmod' the wrong file @Kusalananda :(
Solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't mark it as executable (I did it on the wrong file) -.-

Here it is how you do it if you don't know:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-run-from-a-termi